# Downloads in Flutter web app fail on android Chrome

Tags: download, flutter-web

My flutter web app creates files (csv and pdf) that should be downloaded on user click. It works fine on PC Chrome but fails on Android Chrome. No downloaded file is shown and a file named ".com.google.Chrome.xxxxxx" is stored (where the suffix is random).

Here is my code:

```
import 'dart:html' as html;

void saveFile(String name, dynamic data, String type) {
  final blob = html.Blob([data], type);
  html.AnchorElement(href: html.Url.createObjectUrlFromBlob(blob))
    ..download = name
    ..click();
}
```

I pass either the result of pdf.save() or the csv String into the data parameter.

I also tried this and it works perfectly on the same android Chrome (but I can't set the file name in this case and the automatically generated file name looks awful):

```
import 'dart:html' as html;

void saveFile(String name, dynamic data, String type) {
  final blob = html.Blob([data], type);
  html.window.open(html.Url.createObjectUrlFromBlob(blob), '_blank');
}
```

Any suggestions how to fix this?